# Flutter API, wont get the respon i needed. but when i copy the print data, like token and signature to Postman it gave a respon at least

Tags: flutter, api, dart, post

I've create a code that using post value to get data from host to my test file, that generates all the API host wants. and after fulfilling all of the req, it works properly for the first 1-2 days. but after being tested next time it says `invalid parameter request`. try to check and print all the syntax and data that I got from the request and put the data into postman, it works properly. this is the code that I've created for using the API request

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String generateSignature(String path, String verb, String token,
    String timestamp, String body, String secret) {
  String message =
      'path=$path&verb=$verb&token=$token&timestamp=$timestamp&body=$body';
  var key = utf8.encode(secret);
  var bytes = utf8.encode(message);
  var hmacSha256 = Hmac(sha256, key);
  var digest = hmacSha256.convert(bytes);
  String signature = base64.encode(digest.bytes);
  return signature;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  const String consumerKey = 'jQnNwRUUMlvxznfcYIB0uVJzzyeVY4jv';
  const String consumerSecret = 'wc8bVAjytYLnVJPZ';
  const String tokenUrl =
      'https://sandbox.partner.api.bri.co.id/oauth/client_credential/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials';
  const String baseUrl = 'https://sandbox.partner.api.bri.co.id/v1/briva';
  String path = '/v1/briva';
  String verb = 'POST';

  final resp = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(tokenUrl),
    headers: {
      'Authorization':
          'Basic ${base64.encode(utf8.encode('$consumerKey:$consumerSecret'))}',
    },
  );

  if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
    final body = json.decode(resp.body);
    final accessToken = body['access_token'];

    DateTime localTime = DateTime.now();
    DateTime utcTime = localTime.toUtc();
    String time = localTime.toIso8601String();
    String timestamp =
        DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'').format(utcTime);

    String timeplus1day = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
        .format(utcTime.add(const Duration(days: 1)));

    final data = jsonEncode({
      "institutionCode": "J104408",
      "brivaNo": "77777",
      "custCode": "1255",
      "nama": "John Doe",
      "amount": "20000",
      "keterangan": "",
      "expiredDate": timeplus1day
    });

    String tokens = 'Bearer $accessToken';

    String signature =
        generateSignature(path, verb, tokens, timestamp, data, consumerSecret);

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(baseUrl),
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'BRI-Timestamp': timestamp,
        'BRI-Signature': signature,
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
      },
      body: data,
    );

    print('Generated signature: $signature');
    print('Generated token: $tokens');
    print('Generated timestamp: $timestamp');

    print('URL: $baseUrl');
    print('Request body: $data');
    print('Response: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.body}');
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to obtain access token: ${resp.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

and this is the print result I got from it

```
Generated signature: Sm6kTu6hdS0T3LP+1NshIujv6rXKw1JXwzhikwRCT8E=
Generated token: Bearer CfUClN8TTyGqBeQ2D5POQN6fTxn1
Generated timestamp: 2023-04-02T07:48:03.678Z
URL: https://sandbox.partner.api.bri.co.id/v1/briva
Request body: {"institutionCode":"J104408","brivaNo":"77777","custCode":"1255","nama":"John Doe","amount":"20000","keterangan":"","expiredDate":"2023-04-03 07:48:03"}
Response: 400 - 
                {
                    "status": {
                        "code": "0109",
                        "desc": "Invalid request parameter"
                    }
                }
```

it says invalid request parameter, but when I put it into postman API, it works just fine.

[image]

[image]

and also I integrated the step that I've been told to try.
this is when I try to change the headers into all lowercase. and still got a response from postman API.

[image]

Comment: No it’s not working in Postman neither, the status code is still 400, however the errors seems differents, can you add a link to the api docs?

Comment: sure, here you go https://developers.bri.co.id/en/docs/briva @Barry

Comment: Try calling the api with different customer data parameters, and it should work. seems like there is a conflict.

Comment: work at postman, but in my flutter app still got the same result when I change the customer data parameters, still got the `invalid parameter request`

Comment: In Postman, try changing the header "BRI-Timestamp" to "bri-timestamp" (i.e. all lower case). Does it still work? (Try the same with the other headers.) The reason to try this is because `http` will lower case them.

Comment: @RichardHeap when i changed it, it still work and not giving me any error of invalid parameter, almost look the same with the postman screenshot screen at top